# What formula would be best to use for returning data from a column after it matches data in another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of names.  One column contains several more names than the other.  The column with the shorter list of names is a subset of the larger one, but may contain names that the larger one does not.
With a copy and paste and the use of filters, I can filter the list to yield the information for the subset I want, but I'd really like to learn how to do this with a formula and what I've tried doesn't seem to work.  A picture is worth a thousand words, so allow me to show you one:

[image]
*This is a work of fiction. Names, characters, businesses, places, events, locales, and incidents are either the products of the author's imagination or used in a fictitious manner. Any resemblance to actual persons, living or dead, or actual events is purely coincidental.*

Now, what have I attempted already?  A good number of things combining formulas and functions with INDEX, MATCH, IFERROR.  I've tried so many things over a span of days, that I couldn't tell you what exactly I used at this point and I think it might be less confusing if I kept my initial attempts at this out of this discussion thread.  I'm open to your suggestions, but I'd like to use a formula that does not involve VLOOKUP.  I believe I need to try to make this work for an Office 365 version of Excel, quite possibly the January 2019 version.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setup is Columns `A:D` then you can use the following formula in cell `D2`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,A:A,0)),INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)),"")
```

Comment: You are a genius, VBasic2008.  That worked perfectly!!